# Purchased business can i keep EIN

Tags: business, purchase

I purchased a small business, it is inc.  I kept the name etc., do I have to obtain a new EIN or can I change the ss information and keep the current number

Comment: Have you read [Do You Need a New EIN?](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/do-you-need-a-new-ein) on the IRS website? If that doesn't answer your question, add appropriate details (e.g. sole proprietor/corporation etc.; where the confusion lies).